# Modernizing Root Sharepoint Site Withour Losing Subsites

Tags: site-collection

I have a hybrid of classic teamsites (under /, e.g. /. /HR,/ IT) along with O365 group and other modern sites (all under sites/).  I tried to replace my root (classic Teamsite) site with a modern site.  It worked, however the root site has a bunch of subsites and all of them were archived.  I restored the whole collection with Invoke-SPOSiteSwap but I still would like to replace just the root site with a modern experience.  How can I do this without losing all those subsites?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only support for modern pages you are after *(not sure how long we should keep calling them that!)* you only have to activate the Site Pages feature.

1. Under `Site Settings` and `Manage Site Features` activate the feature `Site Pages`
2. Go to `Site Contents`, find the newly created `Site Pages` library
3. In this library, create a new page of type `Site Page`
4. Set this as your home page

Comment: Thanks Rune. That worked great.